# Open dBase III DBT (version 0) file for reading

Tags: file-corruption

I don't know a lot about dBase III DBT files, and I want to see it's content. The DBT version is **0**, is the file broken?

The output from the `file` command is the following:

```
dbt_file.dbt: dBase III DBT, version number 0, next free block index 3759263696, 1st item "\354\245\301"
```

How can I see this file contents?

Answer (score 0):

I too got this message trying to open an ISO file which was created in a proprietary format (UDF). In this case, the information about this file being a dBase file is wrong. You can open and extract the image with ISOBuster (which is Windows-only, but it also works via wine).